# Multiple IN subqueries in WHERE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera

I am facing issues when trying to translate the following query from impala to hive 1.1 on cloudera 5.8.

```
SELECT   *
FROM   
table1 t1,table2 t2
WHERE   concat(t1.field1, t1.field2) IN
               (SELECT   concat(T3.field1, T3.field2)
                  FROM   table3 T3
                 WHERE   T3.field3 = 'value')
         AND concat(t1.field3, t1.field4) IN
               (SELECT   concat(T3.field1, T3.field2)
                  FROM   table3 T3
                 WHERE   T3.field3 = 'value')
AND t1.some_field = t2.some_field
```

The error I get here states that I can't do multiple subqueries in the where clause.

> Only 1 SubQuery expression is supported.

I have tried working around this issue by using `union`, but in this version only `union all` is supported. I am not really sure on how I could use a join here to fix this as well.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to rewrite this query so it produces the expected result without throwing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Joins and CTE:

```
with s3 as (SELECT T3.field1, T3.field2
                         FROM   table3 T3
                        WHERE   T3.field3 = 'value')

SELECT   *
FROM   
table1 t1 
       inner join table2 t2 on t1.some_field = t2.some_field
       left semi join s3 on t1.field1=s3.field1 
                        and t1.field2=s3.field2
       left semi join s3 on t1.field3=s3.field1 
                        and t1.field4=s3.field2
```

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation says that you can use CTE.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression

Can you try this?

```
WITH firstConcatResult AS (
    SELECT * FROM 
    table1 t1,table2 t2
    WHERE 
        //first concat
)
SELECT * FROM firstConcatResult f
WHERE  
    //other concat
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use `exists` and proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.some_field = t2.some_field
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table3 T3
              WHERE T3.field3 = 'value' AND
                    T3.field1 = t1.field1 AND t3.field2 = t1.field2
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table3 T3
              WHERE T3.field3 = 'value' AND
                    T3.field1 = t1.field3 AND t3.field2 = t1.field4
             );
```

Comment: Why would this be downvoted?  Hive supports correlated subqueries with `EXISTS`.